# casting php arrays to c# hashtables

Tags: c#, php

I have some multi-dimensonial php arrays being passed down to my c# app.  To pull values out on the c# side, i have to do something like:

```
String example = (string)((Hashtable)((Hashtable)example_info["FirstLevel"])["SecondLevel"])["example_value"];
```

How would I go about removing the need to explicitly cast every dimension as a hashtable?  Do I need a recursive function that builds some sort of List object out of example_info, or should I just not be using hashtables?

Comment: does c# have a JSON parser? you could use a structured format to interchange data?

Answer (score 0):

Here, use this:

```
    public Dictionary<string, object> Parse(string array)
    { 
        Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject obj = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(array);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken> kvp in obj)
        {
            if (kvp.Value.ToString().Contains('{'))
            {
                result.Add(kvp.Key, Parse(kvp.Value.ToString().Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "")));
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I am not using JSON and this doesn't seem to handle multidimensional arrays.